# PHP: Question of static arrays inside functions

Tags: php, arrays, static

This is unrelated to OOP. All I want to know is how practical is using static arrays in functions and does it impact performance in the same way as if they were re-initialized every time on function call or actually less?

Example:

```
function color($key)
{
    static $arr = ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"];
    return $arr[$key];
}
```

Comment: The point is that it’s only initialized once and then stays around like a global variable, just scoped to that function. How “practical” that is‽ Not sure what you want to hear there…

Comment: I know it's initialized once, what I'm asking is how optimal it is performance-wise since I intend to re-use that function. The array being non-static would have to be rebuilt each time from scratch on every function call, which albeit negligible is still bad practice in my opinion. And being static it it only happens once, but at the cost of... what exactly?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). Here we see a textbook example of this bad practice.

Comment: …at the cost of keeping the variable in memory. Which it has to in some way or another anyway, even if it should build it again and again.

Answer (score -1):

When you ask for performance, you can just try :

```
function color1($key)
{
    $arr = ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow];
    return $arr[$key];
}

function color2($key)
{
    static $arr = ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow];
    return $arr[$key];
}
$time1=hrtime(true);
for ($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
 color1(0);
}
$time2=hrtime(true);
echo ‘Execution Time without static in ns :’ . ($time2-$time1);
$time1=hrtime(true);
for ($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
 color2(0);
}
$time2=hrtime(true);
echo ‘Execution Time with static in ns :’ . ($time2-$time1);
```

It will give you very precise execution Time (in ns).

Comment: One should never ever touch the performance measurements if they aren't skilled in statistics. otherwise results will be useless if not harmful

Answer (score -1):

Ok, since I'm still using PHP 7.0 I had to give up hrtime() and resort to good old microtime(). Here's my version of the test, which includes direct array access outside a function:

```
function color1()
{
    $arr = ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"];
    return $arr;
}

function color2()
{
    static $arr = ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"];
    return $arr;
}

$arr = ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"];
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
{
    $arr[0];
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'Time 1: ' . ($end - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
{
    color1()[0];
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo '<br>Time 2: ' . ($end - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0;$i < 10000000; $i++)
{
    color2()[0];
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo '<br>Time 3: ' . ($end - $start);
```

The results are thus:

Direct array access: 1.7380030155182

Function array (non-static): 9.6041390895844

Function array (static): 8.5652348995209

As you can see, the static version prevails over the non-static, but not by a large margin. Overall, it's the same story. And, of course, reading the array contents directly is considerably faster. However, I discovered it's not really the array per se which is the bottleneck here, but the function call itself. Testing **function test() { return true; }** measured up to 6.8210098743439!!! So take that and 1.7380030155182 of the first result and you pretty much get the same thing. Of course, it happens only once when you call the function to assign the returned array value to external variable.

Comment: So you just proved that your test is essentially useless and your concern is utterly pointless.